# Selenium C# Nunit tests are passing in Chrome & Edge, but failing randomly in Firefox with "OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox

I have 23 tests which run and pass in Chrome & Edge browsers, but random tests will fail when run in Firefox with the exception: "OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : Element  is not clickable at point (316,822) because another element  obscures it".

The tests are all trying to click on a "Search" button, but nothing is visible in front of it from what I can see. And the "Loading" icon/spinner is not visible in the browser window.

I have tried several things to get around this issue with no luck, so any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

**Things I've Tried:**

1. waiting for the blocking element to disappear (I believe it's the Loading icon/spinner):
   `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(getIsLoadingIcon()));`
2. checking to see if the blocking element property Displayed is false before moving onto the next step
3. Using the Actions class to move the cursor and then trying to click on the element:
   `actions.MoveByOffset(100, 100).Perform();`
4. Using JavaScript to force a click on the Search button:

```cs
IWebElement searchButton = getSearchButton();
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", searchButton);
```

Comment: seemingly random suggests a timing issue.  Include the full exception in your post... it should include the element that is stealing the click.